# How to use the custom modal popup instead of using the confirm dialog box in ts file in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular6

I have a form in my Angular project where **I am trying to implement custom modal popup instead of using the confirm dialog box** , which appear when customer fill the form and in between he try to leave the form then a custom modal will appear with a message asking y/n to exit

For that I have used CanDeactivate route guard in Angular by accessing angular template reference variable in component class.

I am putting ts code below

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { CreateEmployeeComponent } from './create-employee.component';

@Injectable()
export class CreateEmployeeCanDeactivateGuardService  implements CanDeactivate<CreateEmployeeComponent>   {
    constructor() { }

    canDeactivate(component: CreateEmployeeComponent): boolean {

        if (component.createEmployeeForm.dirty) {
            return confirm('Are you sure you want to discard your changes?');
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

As you can see code contain js inbuilt function confirm() ,  `return confirm('Are you sure you want to discard your changes?');`

```
**I want to replace this with a custom modal popup  how can I do that**
```

Comment: You can try [ngx-bootrap modals](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals)

Answer (score 0):

To my above Question I tried with ngx-bootrap modals and model is working fine

Comment: Can you post a link to working example? I am curious to know how bootstrap modal blocks code execution.